# How to configure iptables file to allow only specific ipaddress on all port and deny all other ipaddress?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables

I require a configuration of iptables file which will allow me connection through only specific ip-address say 10.0.0.1 on all port ranging from 0-5555 and deny all other ip-addresses?

I have tried varies iptables command option but it didn't worked properly. What will be the exact iptables command?

Edit: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Did you checked this ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo Also provide Ubuntu version you are using

Comment: I have tried this one: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.1 --dport 0:5555 -j ACCEPT` by reading documentation and googling. But it didn't worked. After flushing, saving didn't worked also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is something like this

```
#################################################
# clear existing chains
#################################################

iptables --flush
iptables --delete-chain

#################################################
# allow loopback
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow established connections
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow ICMP from 10.0.0.1
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.1 -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT


#################################################
# allow port range from 10.0.0.1
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -s 10.0.0.1 -m tcp -p tcp --match multiport --dports 0:5555 -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# deny all
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

#################################################
# default policies
#################################################

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

#################################################
# save the new policy
#################################################

service iptables save
```

Comment: Thanks, This really worked! Further to this I need to allow icmp ping to that IP only. Where should I do changes for this?

Comment: I add icmp code

Comment: For outgoing and incoming https traffic should I add these additional rules? `iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Only for output `iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` When site return traffic to you aka make session use random port. But `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` will allowe you communication.

Comment: Suppose I need to allow internet connection to same IP address (10.0.0.1) then what  changes I need to do in this script or by default this will allow internet connection also.?

Comment: Sorry I don't  understand you. This ip tables rules are on some pc witch is not have ip `10.0.0.1`. What you wish to allow? Http traffic for pc with ip 10.0.0.1? How is pc on 10.0.0.1 connected with pc with iptables rules?

Comment: I was unable to explain you my problem, sorry for that. My question is: suppose 10.0.0.2 is the machine on which I have ran the script providing access to 10.0.0.1. But will this block my internet access on 10.0.0.2 on which the firewall is configured, I guess no.

Comment: I guess that 10.0.0.2 is connected to swith, router with internet access. `iptabels` rules will not deny internet access.